# Okta Authentication with secure password

Tags: javascript, jquery, okta, okta-api

I have implemented Okta login in my application. I have used '/api/v1/authn' api to login. I have send the input for the service as

```
{
  "username": "{{username}}",
  "password": "{{password}}",
  "options": {
    "multiOptionalFactorEnroll": true,
    "warnBeforePasswordExpired": true
  }  
}
```

Here, the password I sent is visible and is there any way to send it securely.

I have also tried a api with Authorization key as 'SSWS {{apikey}}' and input as

```
{
  "username": "{{username}}",
  "password" : "{{password}}",
  "relayState": "{{relayState}}",
  "options": {
    "multiOptionalFactorEnroll": true,
    "warnBeforePasswordExpired": true
  },  
  "context": {
    "deviceToken": "{{devicetoken}}"
  }
}
```

Here, the device token will be expired after 30 days. Is there a way to get the device token which wont expires or is there any service to renew a device token.

Also, in this service the password is visible. Please help to send the password securely in both the service.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Is there a way to get the device token which wont expires or is there any service to renew a device token.:- No you can't check here http://prntscr.com/fyd78l

Comment: Thanks for your response. Did we need to create another token once expired and pass it to service once in 30 days. How did we send the password securely

Comment: I don't have much idea about it ( i just checked it in one-shot through google). But i am sure that they have a support team. you can chat ad ask their question to them.I hope they will resolve your issue

Comment: Did we need to create another token once expired and pass it to service once in 30 days :- it refresh automatically after each api call if it has to be. check the screen-shot and read it carefully

Comment: In that case, the password is open. How could I secure it

Comment: As i said, i never use it, i just checked on google and got that link. Please ask to the support team of okta regarding all your queries.I am sure they have a very good support team